# Should you provide a crt file to help people validate the certificate on your OAuth2 api?

Tags: ssl, https, oauth-2.0, ssl-certificate

I have an OAuth2 api exposed that runs over HTTPS.  Since OAuth2 relies on the security of HTTPS (doesn't do any of it's own signing) I added a note in the developer docs encouraging developers to make sure they validate the ssl certificate in their client applications.

I noticed that some apps make the crt file publicly available or include it in their client: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby/tree/master/lib/data

I assume this is just to make sure it is using the right certs (and not any system installed ones)?  If so, is it a good idea to make this crt file publicly available to developers on your API page and what is an easy command/way to generate this file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When one makes the certificate public this way, he encourages clients to do binary comparison of certificates, i.e. validate the certificate not in a way defined by corresponding standards by building a certificate chain and validating them) but simply by comparing the presented certificate with the one stored in the client.

This method is broken in several ways:

1. binary comparison doesn't let the client know that the certificate was revoked
2. with binary comparison the change of server certificate would require updating all clients so that new certificate would be included there. Failure to upgrade would mean impossibility to connect.

Consequently inclusion of the certificate and "straightforward" use of such certificate makes no sense, neither for server owners nor for clients.

The only case when binary comparison is applicable is when self-signed certificates are used (in which case building and validating a chain won't work). But self-signed certificates is a bad idea in any case (due to reasons listed above and some other reasons).

Comment: Ok interesting, thanks for the response Eugene.  One thing I wasn't quite clear on - a binary comparison is just comparing the bytes of the file I assume, but if you have the crt file, why wouldn't the user actually validate your ssl certificate with it?  I admit I'm a bit rusty on the details of these certificate chains.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @BrianArmstrong not sure that I understand your question. When the client connects to your server, the certificate is presented by the server and validated by building a certificate chain. In this case the crt file is redundant. So why would you want to offer the crt file?